# Parsing String with JSONTokener to JSONObject OR JSONArray

Tags: java, json, parsing, rest

I'm using the following code to handle REST responses from my server:

```
if (response.getEntity() != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }           
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
        try {
            rr.jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokener);                
        } catch (JSONException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("parsing", "creating json array");
            try {
                rr.jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {                    
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

If the response is an JSONObject, it works perfectly but if the server returns a JSONArray, the second try block also throws although it's correct json.

```
03-30 14:09:15.069: W/System.err(6713): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 314 of [{"__className":"stdClass","char3code":"DEU","fips_name":"Germany","alternate_names":"Germany, Deutschland, Allemagne, Alemania"},{"__className":"stdClass","char3code":"USA","fips_name":"United States","alternate_names":"United States of America, Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika, \u00c9tats-Unis, Estados Unidos"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the reason that this is failing is that when you call `new JSONArray(tokener)` the `tokener` is no longer positioned at the start of the token stream.  Try creating a new `JSONTokener` instance for the 2nd attempt at parsing..